# Larger layout to move around

Tags: java, android, layout, android-layout

I am a newbie, so please be nice.

I would like to have a screen that is similar to angry birds. Where the screen is larger than the view-able area. and the user can move a viewable section around a bigger area.

I don't really want 2 layouts, where you move from layout 1 to layout 2.(Not sure if angry birds does that?)

But I would like the user to move slowly around a bigger area. thanks for any help.

thanks

**EDIT**

Platform - Android

Environment - Eclipse + java

I have looked at the 2 layouts.  swiping between them.  does not really work the way I would like.  Which would be a more controllable movement.

Comment: What's the platform? What's the language? What have you tried so far? And... welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView and if its larger than the phone screen, it will automatically have scrolling.

Comment: Use the HorizontalScrollView then.